# Check if exist database in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, web-sql

I'm developing a Cordova/Phonegap application, Basicaly I want to know: how I can check if database exist?

Before accessing it, to show a message and avoid an SQL error.
Thank you!

Comment: I've answered a similar question: [Phonegap check if database exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125706/sqlite-check-if-database-exist/33674394#33674394)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using webSQL,then

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Calling this line means if a database named 'mydb' exists, then it will open it and if doesn't exist it'll create one.

> openDatabase: This method creates the database object either using
>   existing database or creating new one.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

And to make sure that you don't call a not existing table you can use this line in your device ready

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {  
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
});
```

It will create a table with your desired name if not exists. AFAIK this is the way.