# Cordova sqlite does not create DB on $cordovaSQLite.openDB or window.openDatabase

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to store some data in a sqlite DB at my ionic app. I'm creating the DB and one table with the following code:

```
var db = null;

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova', 'slick'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "kog.db" });
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (id integer, title text, day text, fromtime text, totime text, location text)");
      console.log("android");    
     } else {
      db = window.openDatabase("kog.db", '1', 'kog', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (id integer, title text, day text, fromtime text, totime text, location text)');
      });
      console.log("browser");
    }
  });
})
```

When I'm testing my app, the DB is not created. Neither on my mobile device with the SQLite Plugin, nor testing the App in Chrome with window.openDatabase.

Any advice, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!
Cara

Comment: There is nobody out there who could have an advice?

Comment: sqlite is not gonna work with the browser AT ALL. It invokes native functions that are simply not supported in the browser.

Comment: Same Issue. DB working at chrome not at Device i.e android

Answer (score 0):

The $cordovaSQLite code in the controller should lie within an ionic ready function or deviceready function (deviceready function preferred as ionic ready function sometimes does not fire) otherwise i have seen it to give error.

Your method of using openDB is correct, which lies in the run function. Although ideally it should also have a try catch statement.

Please see my repository's www/index.html and www/js/app.js files for more clarity.

The repo is at https://github.com/vibhutewary/ionic_ngcordova_sqlite_todo

You will find the already built apk in the "platforms/android/build/outputs" folder within the example. I have tested the "ionic run android" command after downloading the code and it works fine.

The version 2 of the above application lies in the "ionic_ngcordova_sqlite_todos_version_2" repository of my github account.
It is same functionality wise but uses Ionic Framework's practices (improved CSS etc.).

Also i would recommend to use alert() function to check if the code within openDB success function is being executed. This can be in a try catch statement.

---

Okay as an update: I am sharing the link to a bare bones example of openDB and INSERT, SELECT here. It uses alert to notify if db is created and then alerts if the value is inserted. It then alerts inserted value using SELECT statement.

Please refer to www/index.html and www/js/app.js files for the code. The git repository is at https://github.com/vibhutewary/ionic_ngcordova_sqlite_creatdb_insert_select

I have downloaded the "ionic_ngcordova_sqlite_creatdb_insert_select" repository and run "ionic run android" and it works correctly. The repository has the already a built apk in the "/platforms/android/build/outputs" folder (this will be overridden on "ionic run android" command). The example here creates a DB, then in the controller, a test message is inserted in the table, then an alert() is used to show the SELECT result from the table.

To check if the DB is created or not, you can use the checkFile method.

You can see the above "ionic_ngcordova_sqlite_creatdb_insert_select" repository's www/js/app.js file for usage as it calls the "cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory" method.

Note that the database lies in a folder called "databases" within this "applicationStorageDirectory" folder.

You can also refer to this post which shows applicationStorageDirectory's usage: [Sqlite: check if database exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125706/sqlite-check-if-database-exist)

Edit: I have seen that Ionic Framework crashes on some phones on start (tested on phone "PHICOMM C630"), so i removed Ionic Framework and included just ngCordova and AngularJS libraries. The resulting solution was this at my repository named "corodova_ngcordova_angularjs_jquerymobile_todos". It is a Todo App with SQLite DB handling. To run the solution without building, type "cordova run android"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this : cordova-sqlite-ext

> https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

After adding this plugin to your app just simply write the following code in your app index.html file and test it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lawnchair.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "dbtesting.db", location: 'default' });
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, data text, data_num integer)');

                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["SINORISE 2", 100], function(tx, res) {
                    alert("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- should be valid");
                    db.transaction(function(tx) {
                        tx.executeSql("SELECT data FROM test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
                            console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be > 1");
                            window.external.notify("res.rows.item(0).data: " + res.rows.item(0).data + " -- should be TEXT");
                        }, function(e) {
                            window.external.notify("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e) + " : " + e.message);
                            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e) + e.message);
                        });
                    });
                }, function (e) {
                    window.external.notify("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e) + " : " + e.message);
                    console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(e) + e.message);
                });
            }, function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR INDEX: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two errors one at the creation of a database for the device and one at the creation of database at the browser. below is a solution of both

Some Android devices restrict to use location parameter along with database name. So provide Location parameter
Change this line

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "kog.db" });
```

to

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "kog.db", location : 1 });
```

and for browser support you need to change these lines

```
db = window.openDatabase("kog.db", '1', 'kog', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (id integer, title text, day text, fromtime text, totime text, location text)');
      });
```

to

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (id integer, title text, day text, fromtime text, totime text, location text)');
```